# Prevent Fancybox from fitting it's height to the view / autoresizing

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, autoresize

I'm displaying a simple div with some content in a popup, and everything looks fine as long as I'm using Fancybox 1.3.1. In version 2.1.3, if the window is shorter, a vertical scrollbar occurs on the popup and part of the inner content is being hidden.
I've tried setting following options to false, but none of these attempts worked:

```
$("a.popup").fancybox({
    autoSize : false,
    autoHeight : false,
    autoResize : false,
    fitToView : false
});
```

Did anyone encounter similar issues?

Comment: You don't need to set `autoSize` to `false` since you are setting `fitToView` to `false`. Fancybox still needs a reference, either your content or the viewport, to set its dimensions. When both are set to `false` expect the unexpected.

Comment: Since `autoSize : false` alone didn't work I tried adding some other options. But you are absolutely right, that was propably too much because using only `fitToView` set to `false` did the trick. Thanks a lot @JFK